# Why am I getting error C:\Program Files (x86)\iverilog\bin\iverilog.exe: unknown option -- O when trying to run this Verilog code?

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, simulation

On Visual Studio, I run this Verilog simulation command, but I get the error message:

```
iverilog -O hello_tb.vvp hello_tb.v 

error C:\Program Files (x86)\iverilog\bin\iverilog.exe: unknown option -- O
```

---

```
module hello(A,B);

    input A;
    output B;
    assign B = A;

endmodule


`timescale 1ns / 1ns

`include "hello.v"

module hello_tb;

    reg A;
    wire B;

    hello uut(A,B);

    initial begin
        $dumpfile("hello_tb.v");
        $dumpvars(0,hello_tb);

        A=0;
        #20;

        A=1;
        #20;

        A=0;
        #20;

        $display("test finished");        
    end
endmodule
```

Comment: @toolic there is no question ... you are making an assumption about what the OP is thinking

Comment: @jsotola - Hi, Sometimes the *implied* question seems obvious, although you're right that things would be improved if an explicit question was being asked by the OP. You or anyone else with > 50 points could comment to the OP to ask them to clarify. As no-one else has done that, I'll do it :) In future, please don't be shy to request missing information from an OP in a [polite comment asking for clarification](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756), rather than just saying what someone else is doing is wrong. That can come across as snarky. TY

Comment: Ahmed Sweillam - Hi, Your *implied* question *seems* obvious, perhaps something like "Why am I getting this error message?". However Stack Exchange is a Q&A site and it works best when the question is stated clearly, along with the reasons why you think that error message is unexpected & what you have already tried, to solve it. In this case, it would help to know why you are trying to use "-O". Did you see it in a book (name it & add an image of the page) or a website (add the link) etc.? TY

Answer (score 5):

`-O` is not a supported option for the `iverilog` command, as the error message clearly shows.

One way to see what options are supported is to use the `-h` option to get help for the command:

```
iverilog -h
Usage: iverilog [-ESvV] [-B base] [-c cmdfile|-f cmdfile]
                [-g1995|-g2001|-g2005|-g2005-sv|-g2009|-g2012] [-g<feature>]
                [-D macro[=defn]] [-I includedir]
                [-M [mode=]depfile] [-m module]
                [-N file] [-o filename] [-p flag=value]
                [-s topmodule] [-t target] [-T min|typ|max]
                [-W class] [-y dir] [-Y suf] [-l file] source_file(s)
```

The option you are looking for is the `-o` option (lower case letter "o", not upper case "O").

Another way to find the supported options is to read the `iverilog` documentation.

---

There is another problem with your code:

```
    $dumpfile("hello_tb.v");
```

That will write out the VCD waveform file, clobbering your Verilog testbench file of the same name (`hello_tb.v`).  It is conventionalt to use a `.vcd` file extension for VCD files.  Use:

```
    $dumpfile("hello_tb.vcd");
```